# Generate vectors from single values in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have vector c:

```
c = [2 5 3];
```

I want to generate vectors with their lengths equal to each value in `c` in a consecutive order. So, I should obtain 3 vectors:

```
c1 = [1 2]; 
c2 = [3 4 5 6 7];
c3 = [8 9 10];
```

Next, I want to align these vectors in a 1x3 cell array:

```
out = {c1 c2 c3};
```

This may seem straightforward, but I can't figure how to do it automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) to accomplish this. We first create an array from `1` to `sum(c)` and then use `mat2cell` to group the array into pieces where each piece is the size of each element of `c`.

```
out = mat2cell(1:sum(c), 1, c);
```

This reduces the need for intermediate variables and gives you your cell array directly.

```
out{1} =

     1     2

out{2} =

     3     4     5     6     7

out{3} =

     8     9    10
```

Comment: Why not the much more straightforward `out = accumarray(sum(bsxfun(@gt, 1:sum(c), cumsum(c(:))),1).'+1, 1:sum(c), [], @(x){x.'})` ? :-P

Comment: @LuisMendo Or the [MATL version](https://matl.suever.net/?code=s%3AlGY%7B&inputs=%5B2+3+5%5D&version=19.2.0)